# Delegating server side validation on the client side

Tags: .net, class

Here is my thought process. I have a WCF service and it has some classes and class has some mandatory fields. after calling the service we are validating those data at the service implementation side.

Now I don't like the client to initiate the call if the mandated fields are empty. I want to enforce the client side emitted class to do that for me.

Is my thought is correct or not.

If correct, how can i give delegate this work on the client side, I don't like the create anything thats is called by the service consumers side like call validate method before calling the service.

Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using DataAnnotations on class properties then you can definitely invoke manual validation before actually caling the service.

e.g.

```
public class Recipe
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; } 
}
```

You can trigger the validation on the object using the ValidationContext class from System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.

```
var recipe = new Recipe();
var context = new ValidationContext(recipe, serviceProvider: null, items: null);
var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(recipe, context, results);

if (!isValid)
{
    foreach (var validationResult in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(validationResult.ErrorMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate It. Here externally you have to call this validate method. In WCF we don't know how clients are going to implement the service . That's why I want to enforce this to be done on the client side without giving the option for the client to call the method.